# java inter-process communication

Tags: java, swing, ipc

is it possible to use run a java class in command line to run a certain class or function in a running swing?

such as , when `java Test asd` will setText a running swing Jlabel to asd

Comment: It is doable but not a good design .

Comment: @org.life.java: How do you know it's not a good design?

Comment: @Lukas Eder  He tries to communicate between two process, that can be done by using some other technique also, what do you say

Comment: It is a very sux idea , but I am lack of option because I am doing my final year project and my lecturer want me to use a proprietary software "vitamin d video" that do human detection and able to run a command line when detect one. So I need to show human activity in my java swing ...

Comment: I don't have the hacking skill to understand the assembly code , so i just go with this method ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straight forward way is to create an RMI method call.

It's built into java from the beginning, reasonably simple and lightweight.

Answer (score 9):

The two programs run in separate processes. You will need to create an interface between the processes (or as Matthew put it: implement `inter-process communication`). There are millions of ways to achieve this, just to name a few:

- Create a file-based interface (Test will write into a file and JLabel will read that file)
- Create a TCP/IP connection between the two
- Create a HTTP connection between the two (JLabel may run a glassfish thread or something like that)
- Create a JMS connection
- Create an RMI method call
- Create a Webservice (again with JLabel running glassfish)
- Many more...

Comment: You might want to add that  this is called [inter-process communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipc).